# I am trying to create Microsoft azuer database and create table. What is this error "type 'that could not be found."

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

I am trying to create a Microsoft azure database and create a table. But indicate an error after running the program.

**Employee**

```
 package com.javatechie.azuresql;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private  String dept;
    private long salary;
}
```

**EmployeeRepository**

```
package com.javatechie.azuresql;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
}
```

**SpringbootAzuresqlApplication (main)**

```
package com.javatechie.azuresql;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringbootAzuresqlApplication {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repository;

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        return repository.save(employee);
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootAzuresqlApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
   spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:jdbc:sqlserver://javatechi.database.windows.net:1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
    username: javatechi
    password: password.123
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

server:
  port: 9191
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javatechie</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-azuresql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-azure-sql</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>table</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**this is an error**

> Description:
>
> Field repository in
> com.javatechie.azuresql.SpringbootAzuresqlApplication required a bean
> of type 'com.javatechie.azuresql.EmployeeRepository' that could not be
> found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.javatechie.azuresql.EmployeeRepository' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

- If you don't add the `@ComponentScan` annotation, your main class won't scan the package of  services and won't initialise the beans.
- Bean hasn't been created, therefore Spring is unable to inject it. By using the annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages='pl.springBootStarter.app')` on any of your configuration classes or classes annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, you must instruct Spring to produce implementation of defined repository interfaces. That may solve your issue.
- Altering the spring boot version may also help to fix the problem.